# How do I start guitar 'tapping' style?

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, harmonics, guitar-tapping

I have been thinking of adding tapping guitar style to my fingerstyle and I was wondering if anyone has some tips or useful websites that could teach me this. If anyone has info on how to get louder picked harmonics that would be useful also. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Picked harmonics are always more successful when plucked close to the bridge of the guitar. Love to know why!